# Grails - Autocomplete, receive a list, easiest way 2014

Tags: jquery, grails, autocomplete

I need to enter text in an inputtext having the autocomplete; then choosing the object book.

I have the jquery autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

But I don't understand how I can pass it the ${estrategia.Book.list()}

This is my select, which has the list:

```
<g:select id="estudiante" name="estudiante.id"
    from="${estrategia.Book.list()}" optionKey="id" required=""
    value="${bookInstance?.id}" class="many-to-one" />
```

And this is the JQuery autocomplete, instead of availableTags I need to put the booklist:

```
 <script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

So I created the taglib, without namespace and here is what I am trying, can you point me where is my error?

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="try">Tags: </label>
 <input id="try">
 <g:books id="try"/>
</div>
```

My taglib:

```
def books = {attrs ->
    out << "<script type='text/javascript'>"
    out << "books = ["
    Book.list().each {
        out << "'${it.title}',"
    }
    out << "];"
    out << "</script>"
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

---

EDIT: Well I didn't explain everything I wanted to do... and it results that jquery already does it for you:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: twitter.github.io/typeahead.js is another JS Library that can achieve what you're trying to do which also has a grails plugin (grails.org/plugin/twitter-typeahead). There is an autocomplete tag in the RichUI grails plugin (grails.org/plugin/richui) that has autocomplete as well (not sure what it uses under the covers might just be jquery). I don't know which is the best for your situation I just wanted to post some other autocomplete options for you/others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar and I just created a taglib to do it:

```
def books = {attrs ->
    out << "<script type='text/javascript'>"
    out << "books = ["
      Book.list().each {
        out << "'${it.name}',"
      }
    out << "];"
    out << "</script>"
}
```

And then on the GSP where you have javascript that needs it you would just do:

```
<foo:jsNodeTypes/>
```

where `foo` is the namespace you gave your taglib.

Alternately you could use ajax and have the autocomplete request the data from the server as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Gregg, I will try it before tomorrow.

Comment: I would probably not do a `Book.list()` because you'll be populating all of the properties on that object and potentially related objects depending on your lazy/eager settings.  That could be a performance issue down the line.  I would query for only the data that you need.  You can use `executeQuery` (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) For example `Book.executeQuery("select b.id, b.name from Book b")`

Comment: Well Jarred that seems like something very important that I was missing, actually I call 3 different Domain.list(), for like 2 times each. Every time I call the .list() I get an extra delay or just the first .list() makes it? e.g. one g:select has Book.list() and another g:select in the same GSP has Book.list()

Comment: @Gregg, can you explain a little more? I updated my question.

Comment: Is there any limit? For example if I try to list() 314 rows, it doesn't display anything. (the Strings are like: Perez Contreras, Juan Alberto)